# Chef - ArgumentError: too short control escape

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I will glad to get an any help in the next issue:

when I run a numerous recipes (when I run an each in a separate way it doesn't fails), I sometimes get a next error:

> "ArgumentError: too short control escape"
>
> log:
>
> [2016-03-15T15:41:55+01:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
>
> [2016-03-15T15:41:55+01:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
>
> [2016-03-15T15:41:55+01:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>
> [2016-03-15T15:41:55+01:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
>
> [2016-03-15T15:41:55+01:00] FATAL: ArgumentError: too short control escape
>
> chef-stacktrace.out:
>
> Generated at 2016-03-14 15:56:29 +0100
>
> ArgumentError: too short control escape
>
> C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/formatters/error_inspectors/resource_failure_inspector.rb:66:in 'recipe_snippet'
>
> C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/formatters/error_inspectors/resource_failure_inspector.rb:43:in 'add_explanation'

It happens randomly and I can't to find an explanation,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep investigations, we have found the root cause of the issue. The name of the Github repository was interpreted by Chef as an escape character (the name of repository was starting with capital letter "C") which caused the configuration to fail alternately.

It regards to Chef 12.0.3 version (I hope, they fixed it in a newer next version)

We changed the name of repository and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something is going wonky with the regexp compile. It supposed to use `Regexp.escape(source)` but something might be slipping through? Please include the full error output though.

Comment: It answers that there is a misplaced regexp control code.