# Chef Cookbook Upload error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

While attempting to upload my cookbook to the server, I'm getting the following error statement.
    "Uploading first_cb     [0.1.0]
    ERROR: ArgumentError: too short control escape"

And the command was:
 
    $ knife cookbook upload first_cb
The default.rb contains the foolowing code:

```
package "httpd" do
    action :install
end

service "httpd" do
    action [:enable, :start]
end

template "/var/www/html/index.html" do
    source "index.html"
    mode "0644"
end
```

**knife.rb**

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__) 
log_level :info 
log_location STDOUT 
node_name "ktgirish" 
client_key "#{current_dir}/ktgirish.pem" 
chef_server_url "https://api.chef.io/organizations/girish123" 
cookbook_path ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Maybe an unescaped character in your paths or knife.rb?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111835/chef-argumenterror-too-short-control-escape

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.. I'm very new to Chef.. Could you please tell me what do you mean by unescaped character?

Comment: Can you paste your knife.rb here? Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows machine as workstation and ubuntu as node. Here is the knife.rb :<br> `current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "ktgirish"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/ktgirish.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/girish123"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]`

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111835/chef-argumenterror-too-short-control-escape

Comment: Looks like this issue was fixed: https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/3357
What's the chef version you are using? Is it >=12.10.24

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass source 'index.html.erb' instead of index.html.
you need to create and index.html.erb file in the template folder.